# Get the date in a given format from a String Java

Tags: java, string, date

I have a string that contains a date in the format "MMMM DD, YYYY".
I want to verify the date is in that format, without splitting the String.
The string I have is : `Release Date: February 28, 2019`.
I was thinking that I could use the method contains() and give the format as a parameter in order to return true if the date February 28, 2019 is of that format.
How can I do it ?

Comment: Use a `SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy")`. If you can parse the string to a `Date` object, then its the proper format. Full code would look like this: `new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy").parse("Release Date: February 28, 2019".split(":")[1].trim());`

Comment: "*MMMM DD, YYYY*" - four digits for the month? That is... extraordinary.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, `SimpleDateFormat` won't ignore the "Release Date:" part of the String.

Comment: @kshetline split at `:`, then trim and pass the second element

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, yes, I know you could split the string that way, but the poster specifically stated she didn't want to split the string. What she had against doing that, I have no idea.

Comment: @kshetline probably because the exercise forbids it explicitly ;)

Comment: Works just as well with `subString(14)` @kshetline

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: If the text “Release Date” is fixed, you can make it part of the format pattern string you use for parsing if you enclose it apostrophes: `LocalDate.parse("Release Date: February 28, 2019", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'Release Date: 'MMMM d, uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH))`